# How to disable implicit decoding ("upgrading") in Perl?

Tags: perl, unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Quoting the Perl Unicode FAQ ["What if I don't decode?"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html#What-if-I-don%27t-decode?)

> Whenever your encoded, binary string is used together with a text
>   string, Perl will assume that your binary string was encoded with
>   ISO-8859-1, also known as latin-1. If it wasn't latin-1, then your
>   data is unpleasantly converted. For example, if it was UTF-8, the
>   individual bytes of multibyte characters are seen as separate
>   characters, and then again converted to UTF-8. Such double encoding
>   can be compared to double HTML encoding (&amp;gt;), or double URI
>   encoding (%253E).
>
> This silent implicit decoding is known as "upgrading".
>   That may sound positive, but it's best to avoid it.

Disabling this implicit decoding would force the programmer to use `decode()`/`encode()` properly and help prevent bugs.

Is it possible to turn off implicit decoding? Ideally, using a binary string together with a text string would result in an error.

Comment: Detecting that kind of problem is possible, but Perl would need to start assigning *meaning* to strings: text vs bytes vs unknown. Then, if a func that expects text gets bytes, it could warn or die.

Answer (score 2):

I hate that passage. Perl never implicitly decodes strings using iso-8859-1. For starters, Perl has no way of knowing if the string has been decoded or not.

Consider the following:

```
my $num_apples = 4;
my $num_vegetables = $num_apples;
```

Did Perl implicitly convert a fruits into vegetables? No! Well, then why would you say it implicitly decoded using iso-8859-1 in the following?

```
my $bytes = "\x61\x62\x63\xE9";
$bytes =~ /♠/;
```

In the first snippet, you treated what were supposedly apples as vegetables. In the second snippet, you treated what were supposedly bytes as unicode code points.

If you have a function that expects a string of Unicode characters, and you pass

```
"\x61\x62\x63\xE9"
```

to it, it will be treated as "abcé" because Unicode code point 0x61 is "a", Unicode code point 0x62 is "b", etc. No decoding happens. Perhaps you got that string from using

```
decode('UTF-8', "\x61\x62\x63\xC3\xA9");
```

or

```
decode('iso-8859-1', "\x61\x62\x63\xE9");
```

but maybe you didn't use `decode` at all and simply started with

```
"\x61\x62\x63\xE9"
```

or

```
read($bin_fh, $buf, 4)
```

That doesn't mean that Perl implicitly decoded anything. Since no implicit decoding occurs, it's impossible to turn it off. The answer is no.